# Confuse publish configuration on ASP.NET for x64

Tags: c#, asp.net, 64-bit, publish

I have an application on VS 2008 with .NET 3.5 that was configured for Any CPU. Due a migration (All servers, Dev, Support, Stage and Production were migrated to x64 2008)

I had to change this just to x64. I cleaned the solution, I set to "false" all System.anything references with "copy local" set to true (because if not the application doesn't work on my Dev Environment even)

But when I publish the site to get all the needed files for copy them into the Dev Env, I still get a x86 compilation and then, inside of the bin folder, a folder called x64, and inside of it, a folder called "Debug" with a lot of my own dlls, so I've a folder with that strange name (Debug) with a second copy of the files that I've on the bin folder.

I touch a lot of things trying to fix this situation, read a lot on google (that retrieves a lot of nothing-to-do-here webs and forums) but I can't get what I need to configure to do a clean publish of my asp.net site and their libraries only on x64 without a second copy of nothing and right configured.

So my question is... someone can give me a detailed answer, link, tutorial or something like to publish in a rule way my site, clean and without all this things?

- Please comment if you not understand something of this question, I'll
  update it with more required information.
- Please comment if you will downvote this question to improve it.
- Please avoid answers or comments like "why are you working on VS2008", I'm working under client requirements.

Thanks and kind regards.

UPDATED:

It create a folder in the x64 folder for every publication profile, but some are empty and Debug is always fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. The folder it was an excluded folder from the solution. These files can be showed from the image button on the toolbar of the Solution Explorer window: "Show all files".

Publication also publish exclude folders and files. You must delete them in order to not be published with the other files.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the application to any CPU then when you publixhing it choose "only files needed to run this application", this will do the trick.
If you don't want to set all dll-s to copy local put them into the enveronments' GAC with gacutil. (Not all dll will work this way.)

Comment: Are you removing all previous files on publishing?